# Wordpress Ecommerce Chase Paymentech Integration

Tags: plugins

Just wondering, If any body have integrated [Chase Paymentech Payment Gateway](http://lab.chasepaymentechxpress.com/Integration/Integration_Tools/Commerce_Web_Services.aspx) with WordPress for Shopping Cart purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best source for information on this is the getshopped.org/forums/ forums. It appears that there are a couple of posts regarding this gateway in the forums, but the forums appear down at the moment.

Also, getshopped.org maintains a directory of developers that can help you develop a new payment gateway. These gateways are relatively simple to build (I'm working on one right now) depending on the complexity of the merchant API.

There's no reason that the gateway cannot be build; it's just a matter of finding someone to do it. And, I do not believe that the gateway you are looking for currently exists.

Answer (score 1):

We have developed a plugin that integrates into the Shopp Ecommerce platform for WordPress that allows for accepting payments through Chase Paymentech. Visit our website or send me an email: support at getrouty.com

http://www.getrouty.com

We have also created a Virtual Terminal for Chase Paymentech plugin that can be used in WordPress to accept payments through the administration end, useful for in person or phone orders.